# What to do with maps-related tags for ios?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of today's release of iOS 6, iOS no longer has a Google Maps-based maps app built in.  However, the best-fitting maps tag I could find for iOS is [google-maps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).  Should there be a separate [apple-maps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-maps)?  Or should the existing tag be migrated to something more generic, maybe [maps.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps.app)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a level of specificity that doesn't need to exist for tags. I would have no problems adding a synonym for all the tags you mentioned in your post to simply [maps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps).

A question tagged [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [maps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) is distinct enough to put you in the ballpark of being able to reasonably accurately answer a question.

The detail goes in the question, the (broad) classification goes in the tags.